# Can we provide liquidity to the Uniswap pool from an address other than the admin address

Tags: ethers.js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, uniswap, polygon, uniswapv3

I've created a pool (https://app.uniswap.org/#/pool/8286) on mumbai testnet of polygon mainnet. Our functionality include adding liquidity to the pool from the user's account so the users' might come and provide the liquidity to the pool, after which supposedly they should get some lptokens depicting their holdings in the pool.
And the user would be able to stake those lptokens.

*So for the run down I was testing with my second account on metamask.*

**Question: 1**. Earlier there used to be an option on the top right of the pool that allowed us to directly add liquidity to the pool from the uniswap's interface itself. That option seems to be available only to the owner of the pool now. Does any one know why?

**Question: 2**. Since the add/remove liquidity option was missing from the uniswaps interface I created my own interface integrating the uniswaps SDK to add/remove liquidity. So when I provided liquidity from my second account. I didn't got any lp tokens? Do you know why? Liquidity in the pool has increased though.

I've provided the link of the pool for your refrence, remember the pool is on mumbai testnet. If possible please help!!

Thanks In **Advance**!